# Use 2 inputs from different html site for one app.route?

Tags: python, flask

Hello I have a question about the Python Flask application. I've been looking all the time, but can't find a suitable solution ..

I would like to search for certain columns from this data set using an input.
Then I want to multiply these columns with another input foat input and print them on *'calculate.html'*

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
df=    
    A           B(m)         C(cm)      D(m)
    house        50           50        100
    bedroom      80           50        600
    bed          20           60        500
```

I have 2 different html pages. The 1st page should pass input 1. The input should be searched in the dataset. Nothing should be printed out.

index.html:

```
<form> action ='/index' method = 'post'>
    <p>< input type = 'text' name='inpt'/> </p>
    <p>< input type = 'submit' name='submit'/> </p>
```

On the 2nd HTML page, the number to be multiplied should then be given. And also it have to print the outputs of this program on this site.

calculate.html

```
<h1>{{inpt}}</h1>
<form> action ='/index' method = 'post'>
    <p>< input type = 'text' name='inpt2'/> </p>
    <p>< input type = 'submit' name='submit'/> </p>
    
    <h3>{{my_column}}</h3>    
    <h3>{{my_numbers}}</h3>
```

Here is my Python script:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    my_numbers = []
    my_column = []
    if request.method == 'POST'
        inpt = request.form['inpt']
        inpt2 = request.form['inpt2']
        output = False
  
    
        for text in df['A']:
            if text == inpt:
                give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
                give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis = 1)
                output = True
        
        if output == True:
           return render_template('calculate.html', inpt = inpt)
           # At this point the program should redirect to 'calculate.html' in order to continue calculating there

           # Here we start to calculate with inpt2
            for column in give_text:
                column_edit = give_text[column]
                my_columns.append(column)
                column_edit = float(column_edit) * float(inpt2)
            
                if '(m)' in column:
                    column_edit = column_edit + 'meter'
                    my_numbers.append(column_edit)
                elif 'cm' in column:
                    column_edit= column_edit + 'centimeter'
                    my_numbers.append(column_edit)

            return render_template('calculate.html', my_numbers = my_numbers, my_column = my_column)
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', content = 'No result')
```

But I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can't use 2 inputs from 2 different sites in one app.route?

Comment: why don't just use 2 different routes? Your code will be simplier and cleaner

Comment: @Daniel Rodriquez I wish I could do it, but I don't know how to connect or split the two.
I'm still a beginner in programming and in Flask

Comment: in this case is very easy, define a new method with a decorator like `@app.route('/new-enpoint', methods=['POST', 'GET'])` and in your form, action should be `new-enpoint` instead of `index`

Comment: You mean, I should put inpt1 in an app.route. Input2 in another app.route?
But how do I get the `give_text` in my 2nd app.rout so that I can start the 2nd part of the program?

Comment: from what i see, `give_text` depends of `inpt`. In this cases when I need data from a previous view, what I do is create an input field, but keep it hidden (idk if it a good practise). Let me write you an answer showing you how to split the routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About how to split the route into 2 separeted routes

index.html

```html
<form action ='/index' method='post'>
    <p><input type='text' name='inpt'/> </p>
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit'/> </p>
</form>
```

(I'm realising now that you do not close your form with the `</form>` and that the open tag `<form>` is malformed too)

calculate.html

```html
<h1>{{inpt}}</h1>
<form action='/calculate' method='post'>
    <input type='text' value='{{inpt}}' style='display:none;'>
    <p>< input type = 'text' name='inpt'/> </p>
    <p>< input type = 'submit' name='submit'/> </p>
    
    <h3>{{my_column}}</h3>    
    <h3>{{my_numbers}}</h3>
</form>
```

view.py

```py
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/index', methods=['POST'])
def index_post():
    my_numbers = []
    my_column = []

    inpt = request.form['inpt']
    output = False
      
    for text in df['A']:
        if text == inpt:
            give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
            give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis = 1)
            output = True
        
    if output == True:
       return render_template('calculate.html', inpt=inpt)
    else:
       return render_template('index.html', content='No result')


@app.route('/calculate', methods=['POST'])
def calculate():
    my_numbers = []
    my_column = []

    inpt = request.form['inpt']
    inpt2 = request.form['inpt2']
    output = False
     
    for text in df['A']:
        if text == inpt:
            give_text = df[df['A'] == inpt]
            give_text = give_text.drop(['A'], axis = 1)

    # Here we start to calculate with inpt2
    for column in give_text:
        column_edit = give_text[column]
        my_columns.append(column)
        column_edit = float(column_edit) * float(inpt2)
        
        if '(m)' in column:
            column_edit = column_edit + 'meter'
            my_numbers.append(column_edit)
        elif 'cm' in column:
            column_edit= column_edit + 'centimeter'
            my_numbers.append(column_edit)

    return render_template('calculate.html', my_numbers=my_numbers, my_column=my_column, inpt=inpt)
```

Also, as [@Adam Barnes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63502861/9304067) said, your indentation is a bit messed up, so I'm not very sure about the part for `inpt2`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! If I run your code I get an Error like: **werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'inpt'**
in this line of code `inpt = request.form['inpt']`
but I will try to fix it.

Comment: If it fails in calculate.html is because I realize I missed the `name` attr in the input for inpt. Should be `<input type='text' value='{{inpt}}' name='inpt' style='display:none;'>`

Comment: no, the error occurs in `index_post`. In this line:`inpt = request.form['inpt']`

I added `name = 'inpt'` but the error still occurs

Comment: and if I change the code to: `input = request.form.get('inpt')` the program no longer gives any output

Comment: weird, if you use the `get` method it will returns you None if the key doesn't exists in the dictionary, that's why it doesn't give you any error now. I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, in my case fails when try to access to `df` because I haven't define it, but the request.form['inpt'] part works ok. Maybe something related with the HTML?

Comment: Ah I think I found the bug. i typed a wrong name in index.html instead of 'inpt'. Oops: P
Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Just one more question. Whenever I want to use an input from one page on another page, do I have to rewrite the input and make it invisible? Or can I also access it directly?

Comment: In my example you wrote down the `inpt` again on `calculate.hmtl` and made it invisible

Comment: That's the only way I know to keep data from a previous form available without saving it in global variables or files. Think that when you do a POST request, the data you receive is the one in the form you are sending. In this case, `inpt` is only sent in the 1st form, but you still needed for the logic to "calculate". Maybe there is another way, more cleaner and better, but it is the only way I know

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is messed up.  My best guess is that it's meant to look like this:

```py
        if output == True:
            return render_template('calculate.html', inpt = inpt)
            # At this point the program should redirect to 'calculate.html' in order to continue calculating there

        # Here we start to calculate with inpt2
        for column in give_text:
            column_edit = give_text[column]
            my_columns.append(column)
            column_edit = float(column_edit) * float(inpt2)
        
            if '(m)' in column:
                column_edit = column_edit + 'meter'
            elif 'cm' in column:
                column_edit= column_edit + 'centimeter'

        return render_template('calculate.html', my_numbers = my_numbers, my_column = my_column)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html', content = 'No result')
```

Note the `for` block and subsequent `return`, along with the `else` clause, have all been outdented one level.  Previously, the `for` block would never be reached, as there's a `return` directly before, it, and the `else` clause would execute when `output != True`, as opposed to when `request.method != "POST"`, which again I assume is what you intended.

As a comment mentioned, you'd do well to split your code up more to make it easier to follow, and harder to make mistakes like this.  It doesn't have to be separate routes, but have the GET and POST handling done by different functions, perhaps.